# How can I easily transfer my laravel site to Homestead that's running on another computer?

Tags: laravel, ftp, homestead

I want to use my desktop windows computer to edit code but I'd like to use my macbook as the server. Currently I have set up [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
to access the website on my windows machine. The next thing I'd like to do is to easily sync the files from my windows machine to the ~/Code folder where homestead is setup on my macbook.

Currently I'm using Filezilla to ssh into my macbook and manually dragging the files into the folder. Though this method seems very inefficient. I am wondering if anyone else has a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Look at ways to setup cross OS shared network folders. (Possibly using Samba?) "Share" the ~/Code directory on your network. When you make changes in the shared directory via your windows machine it will update your macbook and then Homestead.

Why are you doing it that way out of curiosity? Why not just dev on your mac?

Comment: I'm running windows 10 and it crashes every time I try to boot up homestead.

Comment: And my mac is on its last leg.

Comment: That's a bad situation. Well let me know if my suggestion works for you. Only thing I could really think of.